# subrange of a fixed size buffer c++ avoiding raw pointers

Tags: c++, buffer, raw-pointer

I am working on some code which is a state machine, and different classes are responsible for different kind of task, all of which are acquiring data. Upon completing the data acquisition, the data needs to be sent away. The class responsible looks something like this:

```
class SendBuffer {
    std::uint8_t* get_position(/*some arguments to determine buffer*/) {  
        return &buffer[/*at determined location*/];
    }
private:
    std::array<std::uint8_t, MAX_SIZE> buffer;
};
```

Of course, this is not safe at all, because the returned pointer has no information of how long the dedicated slice in the buffer is, etc.

I considered returning `std::span<std::uint8_t>` instead of a raw pointer, but I was wondering what the best practices are here.

Comment: `std::span` is what you want if you want a view into the range.

Comment: And if you don't have `std::span` available (C++20 and later only), you can always return something else that is equivalent, such as `gsl::span`, `boost::span`, or even `std::pair<uint8_t*, size_t>`

Comment: If you do have `std::span`, use it. In C++17 you could possibly do `using span = std::basic_string_view<std::uint8_t>;` to get something similar. You may need to add a specialization for `std::char_traits<uint8_t>` though.

Comment: `std::span` is good you can initialize it from `counted`, `take` and `drop` in `std::views` on `std::array` or `std::vector`: e.g. `std::span sp {buffer | std::views::drop(a) | std::views::take(b) };` this will create a rang from indice **[a,a+b)** on `buffer`. `take` and `drop` avoid overrun by skipping/taking all elements if the input count is higher than available elements. Reorder to  `take(b) | drop(a)` to get the **[a, b)** range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `std::span` ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)) is the way to go. It can be initialized from views, as mentioned in the comments. Alternatively `span`'s member functions provide useful utilities. In case of the question, a single value can be returned as a span using the `subspan(offset, extent)` function.

```
std::span get_position(std::size_t i) {  
    return std::span(buffer).subspan(i, 1);
}
```

For a single value returning a reference might be more useful though. But for subranges of the buffer, `span`'s `subspan`, `first` and `last` are convenient. Some examples:

```
std::array<T, N> buffer;
std::span buffer_view{buffer};    // of type std::span<T, N>
buffer_view.subspan(a)            // range from indices [a, end)
buffer_view.subspan(a, b)         // range from indices [a, a+b)
buffer_view.subspan(a).first<B>() // range from indices [a, a+B) with compile time B
                                  // thus returns std::span<T, B>
```

Note that `subspan`, `first` and `last`have static and dynamic overloads

```
buffer_view.subspan<A, B>() // std::span<T, B>
buffer_view.subspan(a, b)   // std::span<T, std::dynamic_extent>
buffer_view.first<C>()      // std::span<T, C>
buffer_view.first(c)        // std::span<T, std::dynamic_extent>
buffer_view.last<D>()       // std::span<T, D>
buffer_view.last(d)         // std::span<T, std::dynamic_extent>
```

Where upper case letters denote compile time constants and lower case letters can also be run time sizes.